# Why doesn't Path.GetFullName work in C#

Tags: c#, path, resources, filenames

I need to access the full path of a Resource file in my C# vs2010 project to use to create myType variable below. If I manually type the path as

@"C:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\Source\dir5\dir6\Resources\myIcon.png"

the code works and accesses the icon. But if I use:

```
var result = Path.GetFullPath("myIcon.png")
```

The value  in the variable result is the name of the correct directory except with two \ backslashes instead of one throughout i.e.

```
"C:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\dir4\\Source\\dir5\\dir6\\myIcon.png"
```

.  The problem is that I need to derive the result (file name variable)  dynamically and I cant hard code it.

I don't know if I am supposed to manually get rid of the two \ and replace it with a single \ ? Or am I missing something.

```
var result = Path.GetFullPath("myIcon.png");
ToolboxItemWrapper myType = new ToolboxItemWrapper(
    type,
    @"C:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\Source\dir5\ImAdmin\dir6\myIcon.png",
    type.Name);
```

I am re-Editing my question.  I have more than few problems, I am realizing  after reading all the comments and the answers.  So, I will mark the only answer as the answer but the one comment about being careful of using GetFullPath was also a valuable feedback.  Thank you to all.

Comment: What do you mean with "I see in the result"? In the Visual Studio debugger? That's just showing to // to simulate C# syntax, there is only one / in the string.

Comment: @user1298925, I would be very careful calling `Path.GetFullPath("myIcon.png");`. You're working on assumption that current folder is set to some fixed path but it can be any path that can change

Comment: Note that there are plenty of duplicate questions on "how to find path to file in resource folder of a project"...

Comment: I have seen them and I picked Path.GetFullPath using SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are seeing `\\` in debugger, then it is simply debugger escaping the `\` character so string appears the same way as if it were to appear as literal in the code.  Clicking on the small  magnifying glass will bring up dialog that shows true, human-readable value.

Comment: But still it does not work , I mean the icon does not get accessed.

Comment: To confirm, you're seeing it in debugger right?  Second, what do you mean does not get accessed?  Can you click on it with your mouse?

Comment: Yes I see it in the debugger and yes when I use magnifying glass I do see only one backslash. So the question is why if I type :